# How to handle cancellation on Task that wraping a third-party long running method

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task

I using some third-party class that have a long time work call DoLongWork().
When the user want to stop the "DoLongWork" we need to call the method StopWork().
When the DoLongWork method is working the UI need to show some loading bar.

I want to create a third-party proxy class.
In this class I will create a method called StartWork - this method will return Task and when the user is cancel the task using CancellationToken two actions will made:

1) the third-party method "StopWork" will called

2) the UI will stop the loading bar.

I try this but there is some problems catching the cancellation in the third-party proxy class and bubbling the cancellation to the ViewModel class.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource;
    private ThirdPartyServiceProxy _thirdPartyServiceProxy = new ThirdPartyServiceProxy();
    public bool IsUIInLoadingMode { get; set; }
    public async void Start()
    {
        try
        {
            _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            IsUIInLoadingMode = true;
            await _thirdPartyServiceProxy.StartWork(_cancellationTokenSource.Token);
            _cancellationTokenSource = null;
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)/*Issue - This never called*/
        {
            IsUIInLoadingMode = false;
        }
    }
    public void Stop()
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
    }
}

public class ThirdPartyServiceProxy
{
    private ThirdPartyService _thirdPartyService = new ThirdPartyService();
    public Task StartWork(CancellationToken token)
    {
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            _thirdPartyService.DoLongWork();
        },token);

        //?? - Handle when task canceld - call _thirdPartyService.StopWork();

        return task;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not going to work since `_thirdPartyService.DoLongWork();` is not accepting a CancellationToken. The token passed to `Task.Factory.StartNew` only has effect when Cancel is called before the task is actually running.

Answer (score 3):

There's a [couple of common ways to observe cancellation tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads): periodic polling with `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` and registering callbacks with `Register`.

In this case, polling isn't possible, since you don't control the code in `DoLongWork`. So you'll have to register a callback, which is more work.

```
public void DoWork(CancellationToken token)
{
  token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
  using (token.Register(() => _thirdPartyService.StopWork()))
    _thirdPartyService.DoLongWork();
}
```

This wrapper assumes that `DoLongWork` will throw `OperationCanceledException` if canceled by `StopWork`.

The wrapper can then be invoked as:

```
await Task.Run(() => _thirdPartyServiceProxy.StartWork(_cancellationTokenSource.Token));
```

As a side note, I have switched to `Task.Run`; this is because [`StartNew` is dangerous](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html).